# Django built-in login view and errors

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-login

I'm using the `django.contrib.auth.views.login and` `.logout` views. Very handy, worked out of the box, would deploy again AAA+ etc.

The problem arises since I'm not using a separate login page, but rather I have a login box in every page (unless the user is logged in, of course). And so, when the username/password combination is wrong, I get an error.
Which of these three paths should I choose?

- There is a secret way to redirect to next not only on success but also on error. If so, please tell me!
- I write my own login view, putting to use Django's message system in the meanwhile
- I write a login page (well, it's just missing a template) so I can exploit the full awesomeness of the Django auth system.

Comment: I get an error complaining there is no `registration/login.html` template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of possible solutions (first + third choices in your list):

1. You have to provide special login page (that is define `registration/login.html`)
   and for non loged in user each normal page has login form;
2. if user logins normally (this logic handled in `django.contrib.auth.views.login`):

   - for normal page: redirect user to the page from where she loged in;
   - for login page: if there is `next` param, redirect there, else redirect to main page;
3. if user fails to login: redirect (or redraw) login page with errors provided;
4. if user is loged in: normal page provides a link to logout (special page is still there in case if user want's to re-login or login through another account).

In normal pages, login form should have something like this `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}" />`.

In project settings:

```
# in settings.py
LOGIN_URL = '/login'     # this should coinside with url pattern of login view
LOGOUT_URL = '/logout'   # same but for logout view
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/' # url to main page
```

N.B.: I don't use django's buildin logout view instead I use my own: almost the same but does logout only for POST requests. This disallows users to logout by `<img src='my_site/logout' />` malicious code.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer. I am now inclined to provide the login page template, but I have some additional questions: I guess that on the stand-alone login page, the next parameter is set only if I landed there because of a failed login from elsewhere. I access it through `request.post.next`, right? Last question: how are login errors passed? Are they passed as errors on the form?

Comment: Also: I have already taken care of including `request.path` for next, but thanks for the heads up on the malicious code!

Comment: No, user can land on stand-alone login page and have `next` even in normal case: for example you can provide link to login like `my_site/login?next=${some other page path}`. `django.contrib.auth.views.login` view handles those cases + it provides `next` variable to the template. Errors passed as error fields in form object.